# Python помогите перевернуть HEX значение

Tags: python, winapi, gdi, pywin32

Я написал функцию

```
def getPixelColor(x, y, hwnd):
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    color = win32gui.GetPixel(wDC, x, y)
    color = '0x{:06X}'.format(color & 0xFFFFFF)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    return color
```

Но я получаю значение цвета задом наперед 0x404537 (40 45 37) цвет должен быть таким 0x374540 (37 45 40) я уже сталкивался с таким в другом языке программирования и мне помогал формат

```
RGB := Format("0x{:06X}", RGB & 0xFFFFFF) # Это не на Python
```

Но я не знаю как написать это на Python я в нем первый день. Прошу подсказать.

Comment: Напишите, откуда вы взяли код оригинального цвета 0x374540?

Comment: Простите ошибся хотел задавать не на русское сообщество вопрос [Вот отсюда](https://pp.userapi.com/c639427/v639427323/2bc24/4CpMWjMfzbQ.jpg). Я уже сталкивался с таким и мне помогал именно смена формата    RGB:=Format("0x{:06X}", RGB & 0xFFFFFF) но я не знаю как правильно написать это на Питоне я в нем первый день

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Aid, я знаю из за чего это происходит я не знаю как это "исправить" на Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип, возвращаемый функцией `GetPixel`, описан здесь: [**COLORREF**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449(v=vs.85).aspx)

По сути, это просто целое число, в котором закодированы цвета следующим образом: `0x00bbggrr`. Т.е. старший байт 0, потом идет синий цвет, потом зеленый, потом красный. В памяти в байтах это целое число хранится в виде байт в порядке `RR GG BB 00`. Почему так - потому что [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). То что вернула функция `GetPixel` полностью соответствует документации по ней, "исправлять" тут нечего.

При записи цвета в 16-ричном виде коды цветов обычно записываются в порядке `RRGGBB`. Чтобы получить коды цветов в нужном вам порядке, можно привести возвращенное значение к байтам, потом перевести в строку например так:

```
BGR = win32gui.GetPixel(wDC, x, y)  # Число 0x404537
RGB = BGR.to_bytes(3, 'little')  # Три байта 37 45 40 (b'7E@')
color_str = '{:x}{:x}{:x}'.format(*RGB)  # Строка '374540'
```

Вариант от участника **jfs** (для версии Python 3.5 и выше):

```
BGR = win32gui.GetPixel(wDC, x, y)  # Число 0x404537
color_str = BGR.to_bytes(3, 'little').hex()  # Строка '374540'
```

Comment: а нельзя короче в Python? как например у меня в моем примере


    RGB := Format("0x{:06X}", RGB & 0xFFFFFF) # Это не на Python

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович, врядли. В любом случае придется разбивать на байты, а дальше превращать в текстовое представление. Можно конечно две строки в одну скомпоновать, но особого смысла в этом я не вижу.

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович что это за язык, который цифры в числе справа налево выводит? (даже у арабов числа слева направо записаны — точнее когда европейцы их математические тексты переводили, то порядок так и оставили: старшая цифра слева, младшие справа). Чтобы получить строку с  перевернутым порядком байт: `0x404537 .to_bytes(3, 'little').hex()`